# I want to ping an IP via a router on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, routing, ping, router

I have a router which runs openwrt with 3g and an ubuntu PC.

I want to be able to ping an IP: 8.8.8.8 from the PC, but have it routed through the router.

Does anyone know how I'd go about setting this up?

Cheers

Comment: Say what? Do you just want the ping packets to go first through the router? In that case, you need do nothing. Or do you want the ping packets to originate from the router? In that case, `ssh` into the router (which should be possible with OpenWRT, I assume) and run your ping command in that shell.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  Everything going on the Internet goes through a router.   Can you come up with a diagram or something?